# Verbments error when using a caption parameter

Tags: pdftex

When I use the caption parameter for verbments

```
\begin{pyglist}[caption={TEST}]
some code
\end{pyglist}
```

I get the following error

```
file.tex|44 error| Argument of \pl@label has an extra }.
file.tex|44 error| Paragraph ended before \pl@label was complete.
```

The caption is generated and everything works, but I get an error. Any ideas?

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,            % DIN A4
  DIV=10,             % Schriftgröße und Satzspiegel
  oneside,            % einseitiger Druck
  BCOR=5mm,           % Bindungskorrektur
  parskip=half,       % Halber Abstand zwischen Absätzen
  numbers=noenddot,   % Kein Punkt hinter Kapitelnummern
  bibtotoc,           % Literaturverzeichnis im Inhaltsverzeichnis
  listof=totoc        % Abbildungs- und Tabellenverzeichnis im Inhaltsverzeichnis
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{../style/thesisstyle}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{graphicx} %package to manage images
\usepackage{paralist}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{verbments}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata, backgrounds, calendar, chains, matrix, mindmap, patterns, petri, shadows, shapes.geometric, shapes.misc, spy, trees}

\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000

\input{thesisglossaries.tex}  % load acronym, symbol and glossarie entries
\makeglossaries           % create all glossary entries (remember: run makeglossaries manually)

\sisetup{locale = DE}     % siunitx locale setup
%\DeclareSIUnit \fps{fps}  % a custom unit (usage: \SI{24}{\fps})

\begin{document}
\input{configuration/configuration}    % load all settings

\hyphenation{Ba-che-lor-the-sis}

% Cover page here, no page number
\ICoverPage

% Titlepage is page one even if the number is not shown.
\pagenumbering{roman}
% Title page here
\input{../style/titlepage}

% Abstract page here
\input{../style/abstractpage}

% Table of contents here
\tableofcontents

% List of figures here
\IListOfFigures

% List of tables here
\IListOfTables

% List of accronyms here
\IListOfAccronyms

% List of symbols here
\IListOfSymbols

% Uncomment if list of source code is needed (rarely).
%\lstlistoflistings  % requires package listings, needs to uncommenting of usepackage

% path to the chapters folder is set to find the images used there
\graphicspath{ {./chapters/} }

% Chapters
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{chapters/first_chapter}
\input{chapters/second_chapter}
\input{chapters/third_chapter}

%\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliographystyle{dinat}
\bibliography{literature}

% Appendix
\appendix
\input{appendix/example_appendix}

\IGlossary

\Istatement

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please show a full minimal document from `\documentclass` up to `\end{document}`? If I wrap that code snippet in a standard document, I get no error.

Comment: Here is the main.tex

Comment: The problem is with `paralist`. Use `enumitem` instead. In any case, it is a bad idea to load both `minted` and `verbments`.

Comment: Seems to have worked. Thank you!